# Does contra-rotating vs regular propellers, have any effect on icing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, propeller, anti-ice, icing

I am trying to understand whether can there be any correlation between the contra-rotating propellers and the ice accretion over the wing ? For instance, is there any evidence that ice accretion is more in regular propellers when compared to a contra-rotating propeller ?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Are you concerned about total accretion alone, or are you concerned about (a)symmetries as well?

Answer (score 1):

What are the parameters for icing on the wing?

- temperature
- air humidity
- airspeed / pressure

The rotation direction of the propeller does not effect any of this parameters. Therefore the propellers rotation direction does not affect icing.

Comment: This is not true, propeller swirl means the local angle of attack of a wing behind the propeller is affected by the propeller direction and speed.

Comment: @fooot But it does that with opposite effect on either side of the propeller so when we change the *rotation direction* the icing may be affected *locally*, but for the plane as a whole the local changes level out each other.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any engineering study or even theoritical discussion on this topic.  However I can from practical experience say contra rotating props appear to have the same propensity to ice as non contra rotating props.